# How to get Leaflet for R use 100% of Shiny dashboard height

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard

I am in the process of creating a Shiny dashboard application, where the dashboard body is supposed to show some maps. So far no problem to get the map expand over the entire width of the body, but it's somehow not willing to adjust to the full height.
[image]

The leaflet itself is already set to cover 100% of the height, but it doesn't do the trick. As soon as I use the height attribute for the leafletOutput the leaflet object will not show at all, and I am left with an empty box.

The code can be found below:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Maps", 
        tabName = "maps", 
        icon = icon("globe"),
        menuSubItem("Watersheds", tabName = "m_water", icon = icon("map")),
        menuSubItem("Population", tabName = "m_pop", icon = icon("map"))
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Charts", 
        tabName = "charts", 
        icon = icon("bar-chart"),
        menuSubItem("Watersheds", tabName = "c_water", icon = icon("area-chart")),
        menuSubItem("Population", tabName = "c_pop", icon = icon("area-chart"))
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "m_water",
        box(
          title = "Baltic catchment areas",
          collapsible = TRUE,
          width = "100%",
          height = "100%",
          leafletOutput("l_watershed")
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "m_pop",
        # Map in Dashboard
        leafletOutput("l_population")
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "charts",
        h2("Second tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$l_watershed <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(height = "100%") %>% addTiles() %>% setView(19.08, 60.25, zoom = 4) %>%addWMSTiles(
      "http://62.236.121.188/arcgis/services/DataAndMaps/Background/MapServer/WMSServer?",
      layers = "11",
      options = WMSTileOptions(
        format = "image/png",
        transparent = TRUE
      ),
      attribution = "Catchment area provided by HELCOM"
    )
  })

  output$l_population <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(height = "100%") %>% addTiles() %>% setView(19.08, 60.25, zoom = 4) %>%addWMSTiles(
      "http://62.236.121.188/arcgis/services/DataAndMaps/Background/MapServer/WMSServer?",
      layers = "17",
      options = WMSTileOptions(
        format = "image/png",
        transparent = TRUE
      ),
      attribution = "Population data provided by HELCOM"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I personally found, that setting the height relative to window-size is more satisfying. Height as percentage does not work, because the dashboardBody has undefined height. But relative to the whole document is okay.

100% of the dashoboardBody makes 100vh (ccs3-unit) minus header (minimum 50px) minus dashboardBody padding (2* 15px).

So, set the height to 100vh - 80px and you should be fine.

Since shiny does not support css3-units, this has to be included directly to the document, like in the code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
    leafletOutput("map")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(42, 16, 4)
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Have fun!

Comment: You can also use the viewport height(vh) straight in the output: leafletOutput("map", height = "95vh")

Comment: Do not forget that if your leaflet map is from an output function change the #map to the shiny output var name

Answer (score 12):

Another option is what [jcheng5](https://github.com/jcheng5) and [kent37](https://github.com/kent37) have described on [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/59)

```
output$mymap = renderLeaflet({...make a map...})
leafletOutput('mymap', height=1000)
```

Works for me with a `leaflet map` in `R flexdashboard`

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the pixel size manually:

```
...
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "m_water",
        box(
          title = "Baltic catchment areas",
          collapsible = TRUE,
          width = "100%",
          height = "1000px",
          leafletOutput("l_watershed",width="100%",height="1000px")
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "m_pop",
        # Map in Dashboard
        leafletOutput("l_population",width="100%",height="1000px")
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "charts",
        h2("Second tab content")
      )
    )
  )
...
```

Comment: Or in `Box` you can use  `tags$style(type = "text/css", ".box-body {height:80vh}"),` and then `leafletOutput("l_watershed",width="100%",height="100%")`

Comment: Adding the pixel size works... However, the height depends on the screen of the user and cannot be set to a fixed value. Hence, the need for percentage.

Any possibility to get that done?

Comment: The usage of `tags$style(type = "text/css", ".box-body {height:80vh}")` helps and gives the solution! Thanks

Comment: @ThomasBecker `80vh` its not full right -- it s simply 80% from screen.. so may be @K. Rohde versiom will be better

Comment: Yes, the version of @K. Rohde is the more precise way. However, both your replies answer the question and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Th `vh` unit is not working for some old mobile browser. This css below should work for computer and mobile.

```
/* for computer */
div.outer {
     height: calc(100vh - 80px);
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     min-height: 500px
}

@media all and (max-width:768px){
/* for mobile */
div.outer  {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it if you want to combine your leaflet map with another kind of panel structures like a navBarPage, including the map in a tabPanel:

`tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),`
`tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),`
`leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),`

[image: capture of a navBarPage combined with a leaflet map]

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** Unit `vh` not `%`

Viewport height (vh) is percentage of the window taken up.
So this will fill the entire screen vertically:
`leafletOutput(<tag>, height='100vh')`

*(Avoid changing height in `renderLeaflet` and `leaflet`)*

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of @K. Rohde I've been using a [custom css file](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css) containing

```
#map {
    height: calc(100vh - 130px) !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #map {
    height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a varation of the answer from K. Rohde above, which includes the same approach however using shiny modules. Note the addition of the namespace call in the tag$style line to achieve the same result.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)


mod_leaflet_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  fillPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", paste0("#",ns('map')), "{height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
  leafletOutput(ns("map"))
  )
}

mod_leaflet_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(42, 16, 4)
        
    })
    
    }

  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    mod_leaflet_ui("leaflet_1")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 
  mod_leaflet_server("leaflet_1")
  
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```